# Setting a JS variable and using it in html tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables, var

I have set a variable, and I need to pull in this variable into a html element, but I cant get it to print out the value, this is the code:

```
<script>
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
</script>

<div id="<script type="text/javascript">document.write(randomnumber)</script>"></div>
```

Thanks.

Edit: I just used a div as an example, but i need to add a random number to an img tag, as it is for a tracking tag, and needs a unique identifier. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is this for? Why assign a random ID to an element? (Numeric-only IDs are invalid in HTML 4 btw)

Comment: Just inject the div via javascript itself. Btw in html4 you shouldn't have leading numeric id's

Comment: And I'm not even sure you can put script tags inside attributes...

Comment: `document.write`? In the end of 2012?

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
<script>
document.write('<div id="'+randomnumber+'" ></div>');
</script>
```

You can't open a script tag inside an attribute

Comment: the issues with `document.write()` is that it doesn't execute before `</body>`. What if I needed the javascript to execute before?

Comment: @ArturGrigio I'm not sure of what you are saying. It does execute before `</body>`, it executes exactly where it on the page. So if you put it before some HTML it depends on, it would break because it wouldn't find the node (because it hasn't yet been parsed)

Comment: Lets say I had `document.write('<img src="img.jpg">')` when the page starts rendering, JS just writes `<img src="img.jpg">` as plain text, until it reaches `</body>`, and then it renders as an image.

Comment: @ArturGrigio Nope that is incorrect, the image starts loading immediately. You can test it by analyzing the network, if the image is cached, it shows up immediately (add a breakpoint on a separate script tag). The HTML generated by `document.write` is immediately parsed by the browser once the script tag closes.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can create it using `JS`:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
a = document.createElement('div');
a.setAttribute('id',randomnumber);
document.body.appendChild(a);

// if you know the exact class or ID where it is to be appended you can use

document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].insertBefore(a, document.getElementsByClassName("beforeClass").firstChild);
```

This will create a `div`, with the `id` as the `randomnumber` and append it to the `body`

Comment: I don't think you can be using `appendChild` here because the OP seems to want the div to be placed exactly where this code is. Your code will append the div to the end of the body, which probably isn't desired.

Comment: well you can find the specific class or div if you know the exact location, where you need to append it

Comment: @Ian calling `document.body.appendChild(a);` adds it as the last element at that moment, just like `document.write` would

Comment: @JuanMendes I just said that.

Comment: @Ian You said it will be the last thing in the body, that is only true if there is no HTML after the script tag. http://jsfiddle.net/WqbY7/

Comment: @JuanMendes Ahh yes, since this is inline script, that makes sense. Sorry for the confusion. "that is only true if there is no HTML after the script tag" doesn't make sense (it will technically be appended immediately as you said "adds it as the last element at that moment")

Comment: @Ian That wording was for you to understand that it will only the last element of the body if there is no other content after the script tag